# Matrix transformation and boundedness

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have seem in books where they use the fact that a matrix transformation defined everywhere must be bounded.
Can someone help me in understanding why this is true

Comment: They are not bounded in the Calculus sense but they are bounded in the Functional Analytic sense. Are yo familiar with the concept of a bounded operator?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sorry for the late reply. Yes I am.

Comment: That is the existence of a constant $c$ such that $||Tf|| \leq c||f||$ for all $f$

Answer (score 1):

The result is true in finite dimesnsionalspaces but false in infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces. It is well known that there exist discontinuous linear functionals in the latter case ( hence also discontinuous linear maps from the space into itself). So consider a  finite dimensional sapce now. If $\{e_1,e_2,..,e_n\}$ is an orthogonal basis then any vector $v$ can be written as $\sum a_ie_i$. So we get $Av=\sum a_i Ae_i$. Let $C$ be the maximum of the numbers $\|Ae_i\|, 1 \leq i \leq n$. Then $\|Av\| \leq C\sum |a_i|\leq C\sqrt n(\sum |a_i|^{2})^{1/2} =C\sqrt n \|v\|$.

Comment: What if the space is infinite dimensional. Does the statement "defined everywhere" implies the existence of the supremum of the $||Ae_i||$

Comment: Matrix transformations generally refer to finite dimensional spaces. What is your definition of  matrix transformation? @stackuser

Comment: The matrix $A$ associated to a linear operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $H$ with orthogonal basis $e_n$ with entries $a_{ij}=(Te_j,e_i)$. In this case, I am assuming $H$ to be separable.

Comment: You are making no assumption on the matrix $((a_{ij}))$ so the  result is  blatantly false in infinite dimensional case.  See my revised answer. @stackuser

Comment: Thanks. I was referred to the paper by. W. Cohen and N. Dunford, Transformations on sequence spaces, Duke Math.
J. 3 (1937), 689-701.